# how to use to uiviewcontroller without xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have one question about transition.
we use this code when we want to transition to next `UIViewController`:

```
UIViewController* secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

or

when we want to add `NavigationController` using this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

or

when we want add `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController` using this code:

```
UIViewController* secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

now I want to know that if I don't use `xib` file in my project what to do???

Comment: Then are you using storyboards ??

Comment: @vishnuvarthan no my friend no storyboard no xib file

Comment: so u want to do everything programmatically with a Empty Application Template

Comment: @vishnuvarthan yes my friend please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You could use ViewController from Storyboard

```
ViewController *controller = (ViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
```

or create normally

```
// make Layout in viewController - viewDidLoad
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, 320.0, 24.0)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.text = @"My text";
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    UIButton *button = ...;
    [self.view addSubview:button];



}
```

Comment: my friend // make Layout in viewController - viewDidLoad
what does mean?

Comment: You should have to make your Layout in viewDidLoad method of ViewController.

Comment: my friend I am confused!!! this code :ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
is code for making layout???

Comment: No! with this code you create your ViewController instance and in ViewController.m you have to create your layout (method viewDidLoad) .I don't know how can explain it better :/

Comment: sorry my friend. how to create layout (method viewDidLoad)!!! please  guide me!!!